# Sequelize findone query returns NULL when no records found, can i change this NULL to empty object for my all findOne Query?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Can i change findOne query result from NULL to an empty object while there is no data is match. if yes how?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a configuration plugged in sequelize for this option.

You could make a base DAL class for your model access layers.

```js
export class BaseDal {
    constructor(model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    async function findOne(filter, options = {}) {
        let res = await this.model.findOne(filter, option);
        return !res ? {} : res;
    }
}
```

And then every dal related to any of your model will inherit from this class:

```js
import {BaseDal} from './base-dal.js'

class SomeModelDal extends BaseDal {
    constructor(model) {
        super(model);
    }

    function findEntityById(id) {
        let filter = {id: id};
        return this.findOne(filter); 
    }
}
```